# Excel conditional formatting using ADDRESS function

Tags: excel, epplus

In my excel file you can make changes to the content. The cells which are changed should be marked with a different styling (different background color).

I thought i could solve it like

- Create 2 worksheets with the same content
- Create a conditional formatting condition. When the value of Cell A on Sheet 1 is different from the value of Cell A on Sheet 2, the formatting rule fires and the background color is changed.

This does work, for 1 cell. However, I would like it to apply on the entire sheet. The only way that i can make it work for now is to create a formatting rule for each cell which takes a lot more time (in EPPlus, C#).

I tried an unequal to condition like 'Sheet2!B2'. Can i make this function dynamic? Calling the ADDRESS function does not seem to work in this condition.

I would like to generate the sheet using EPPlus

Comment: I'm generating the Excel sheet programmatically using EPPlus in C#. I added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first removing the '$' signs in the conditional formatting formula for A1 and then selecting the entire sheet in 'Applies to' in the Conditional Formatting dialogue - in that order (if that can be done from EPPlus).

But it might be worth considering a completely different approach that does not require a copy of the sheet. I would add a Worksheet.Change event to the workbook module 'ThisWorkbook':

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

End Sub
```